# forEach works on FileList on CRA/Next JS app, but not on Next JS app created with create-next-app

Tags: reactjs, foreach, next.js, create-react-app

I'm just confused. When I used forEach on a FileList on my website that's created using CRA and migrated to Next JS (just the same file), the forEach works. But then when I re-created my website using create-next-app, now I can't use forEach on fileList. And I just tested both of my files, I ran my CRA/Nextjs website, and forEach still works on FileList, but my create-next-app website is getting an error on forEach.

This is a sample of my code:

```
const selectImageHandle = (e) => {
    let arrayImages = [];

    e.target.files.forEach(file => {
        arrayImages.push(file);
    })
}
```

I didn't noticed this at first when I re-created my website using create-next-app, cause it already works on my CRA/Next Js. Thank you!

Edit: the error I'm getting on my create-next-app is

```
e.target.files.forEach is not a function
```

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: @rayhatfield the error I'm getting on using forEach on fileList on my create-next-app is `e.target.files.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Does it work if you do `const arrayImages = […e.target.files]` instead?

Comment: @rayhatfield yea it does, I'm still confuse though, about why forEach works on CRA but not on Next js. I think I'll be using that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your file input just a regular html input or is it a component from a library?

It seems you were previously getting an event where `e.target.files` was an array and now you're getting one where it's an actual [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), which doesn't have a `forEach` method.

The FileList is iterable, however, so as mentioned in my comment above you could do this instead (which has the added advantage of being concise):

```js
const arrayImages = […e.target.files];
```

Without additional information I'm not sure why this would be different between `create-react-app` vs. `create-next-app`. If you're using a standard html input I wouldn't expect any difference, but if you're using an off-the-shelf component or drag/drop target it's possible you picked up a different version of that component that behaves slightly differently in this respect.

Comment: i'm just using a standard html input. I was also getting a filelist on cra, same on create-next-app.